# Order the plotting of data by the contents of a date column

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have dataset as follows:

```
df = data.frame(name = c('Ger1', 'Ger2', 'Ger3', 'Ger4', 'Ger5', 'Ger6'),
            issued = c(UKS, USD, UKS, UKS, USD, USD),
            mat = c(2024-01-31, 2023-01-31, 2026-10-22, 2022-07-22, 2029-01-31, 2025-06-07)
            volume = c(0.476, 0.922, 0.580, 1.259, 0.932, 0.417)
```

I currently plot (and filter) the data using the following code:

```
plot1<- ggplot(subset(df, issued == "UKS")) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(x=volume,y=name),fill="#1170aa")+
  theme(title=element_text(size=12),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill='white',color='black'),
        legend.position='right')+
  labs(title = "Total carriage by Volume on the day", x = "Volume", y = "Name")
```

I'd like to be able to order this data using the 'mat' column as guide, namely with the data that has the earliest 'mat' date at the top of the Y axis and the most distant 'mat' date at the bottom. Does anyone have any advice on how to achieve this?

Edit: I use grid arrange to plot it against another chart.

```
grid.arrange(plot1,plot2,ncol=2)
```

Sadly I get the following error:

```
Error in `-.POSIXt`(Maturity) : unary '-' is not defined for "POSIXt" objects
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I was able to fix the ordering issue by appending the mat column data to the name, and then adding:

```
+scale_y_discrete(limits=rev)
```

To the end of the ggplot code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stats::reorder()` inside `aes()` to reorder the bars. If a `factor` is supplied you don't need to supply a `FUN`, but for a continuous variable like `Date` you can specify the way to sort. In your data (although you didn't post it this way in the question), it seems your `mat` variable is `POSIXlt`. This format cannot be directly operated on as a numeric. Instead, I suggest using `POSIXct` and then it will work. See `?stats::reorder` for more info on how to control this. Another option is to set levels of the factor in the data before passing to `ggplot()` which might be a better option if you have complex sorting to do.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(name = c('Ger1', 'Ger2', 'Ger3', 'Ger4', 'Ger5', 'Ger6'),
                issued = c("UKS", "USD", "UKS", "UKS", "USD", "USD"),
                mat = c("2024-01-31", "2023-01-31", "2026-10-22", "2022-07-22", "2029-01-31", "2025-06-07"),
                volume = c(0.476, 0.922, 0.580, 1.259, 0.932, 0.417))

df %>%
  mutate(mat = as.POSIXct(mat)) %>%
  filter(issued == "UKS") %>%
  # mutate(name = fct_reorder(.f = name, .x = mat)) %>% ggplot(aes(volume, name)) +
  ggplot(aes(x = volume, y = reorder(x = name, X = mat, FUN = sort))) +
  geom_col(fill = "#1170aa") +
  labs(title = "Total carriage by Volume on the day", x = "Volume", y = "Name") +
    theme(
    title = element_text(size = 12),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white', color = 'black'),
    legend.position = 'right'
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for the quick response. I seem to be getting an error on that: "Error in `-.POSIXt`(Maturity) : 
  unary '-' is not defined for "POSIXt" objects" Namely on my grid.arrange line.

Comment: You supplied the `mat` column as `character`. But it's actually stored as a date in your data. I'll edit my answer to update...

Comment: Hi again, thanks for looking into this. Seem to be making a bit of progress, but now I am getting: "Error in sort.int(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing, ...) : 
  'x' must be atomic"

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's an issue with the formatting of your data. Try to copy paste from my example. If they works, please share `str(df)` to help troubleshoot further